# How do you promote a second generation package

Tags: salesforcedx

I have all the permission set according to the documentation. I also have a perm set assigned to create and update second gen packages.

Second Gen packaging beta is enable in the dev hub org...

Every time I try and promote a package version I get the following error:

> You don't have the correct user perm to promote a package version to released. Ask your Salesforce admin for help.

Any ideas on where to look to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. I did not see it in the docs but after some looking you need to have the

> Promote a package version to released

Permission